# How are these clickable html items made clickable without an a-html-tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand an existing web site. The site seems to be built using php, javascript and html. One table in a generated html page contains a lot of players, including rank, name, club etc. The player name is clickable and a click will give further information about that player. I just don't understand why the name is clickable, and what code that states what should happen when you click, since no a-html-tag etc is present in table. There must be some php/javascript/html magic at work here that I do not understand.

Below is an extract of the html code for the table, for the first of 500 players, where the player name "Persson, Jörgen" will become clickable.

```
  <table>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>Placering</td><td>Namn</td><td>Född</td><td>Klubb</td><td colspan='2'>Poäng</td></tr>

<tr><td class='hoyre'>WR43 1</td><td>(1)</td><td><span class='rml_poeng' id='rml:41118:159:0'>Persson, Jörgen</span></td>
        <td>1966</td><td>Halmstad BTK</td><td class='hoyre'>2516</td><td>(-22)</td></tr>
```

To reach the site and the table:
* Go to http://www.cupassist.com/pa/login.php 
* Click on the blue and yellow logo with the text "SVENSKA BORDTENNISFÖRBUNDET" 
* Click on "Ranking" 
* Click on "Listor"

Now you should see a list of 500 players. You can now show the page source for this page to view the full code that the extract above was taken from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is used to bind a `click` event handler to the element (in this case, all `span` elements with a class named `rml_poeng`):

```
'span.rml_poeng' : function(element)
{
    element.onclick = function(e)
    {

        id = this.id;
        vis_poengdet(e, id);
    } 
}
```

An example of one of the clickable cells:

```
<span class="rml_poeng" id="rml:41118:159:0">Persson, Jörgen</span>
```

The JavaScript uses some library that appears to be called `behaviour.js`, which allows the selection of DOM elements using CSS style selectors (much like jQuery does).

You could dig further to find the implementation of the `vis_poengdet` function. Just use Firebug or Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Likely it would be much more efficient had the author of that page put a single listener on the table, then dealt with click events as they occurred.